# javascript .map not working with react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't know if I forgot anything but `.map` is not returning the expected components.

This is my code:

```
    data(){
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
          var uid = user.uid;
          axios.get('apilink here'+user.uid).then(function(response){
             var arr = Object.values(response.data);
             var listItems = arr.map(function(item){
               return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
             }) 
          })
      }
```

and this what I'm rendering:

```
render() {
        return (
          <Container style={{backgroundColor:'#F7F7F7'}}>
            <Content>
              {this.data}
            </Content>
          </Container>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does `not working` mean? Not working how? Any errors? If so, what?

Comment: Isn't that invalid JavaScript? `<` is interpreted as "less than" and `>` is interpreted as "greater than". Did you mean to put that in a string?

Comment: can u paste your sample response object here? -> `response.data`

Comment: @SumnerEvans It's part of React.js.

Comment: @Barmar, OK. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: you just need to invoke it --> `{this.data()}`

Comment: this will not work. you need to set the result of axios/after map into the state of the component to make this work..

Comment: and that ^, you will need to setState with the response of the api call to cause a re-render once the data has arrived

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this in the wrong way. Your `data` function is not returning anything first of all so it won't display anything in your render method. You can debug that by simply calling your function and you will see that the value returned is `undefined`.

You are loading data from a remote resource, according to docs a good practice is to handle this in `componentDidMount`:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. **If you**
>   **need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to**
>   **instantiate the network request.** Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

So one way to approach this would be to move your `data` code into `componentDidMount()` and update the state of the component once the data has been retrieved. Something like this:

```
...
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { data: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var uid = user.uid;
  axios.get('apilink here' + user.uid)
    .then(function(response){
      var arr = Object.values(response.data);
      this.setState({ data: arr }); 
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <Container style={{backgroundColor:'#F7F7F7'}}>
      <Content>
        {
          this.state.data
            .map(function(item) {
              return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            })
        }
      </Content>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't use your `data()` function directly in your render method because it's async.

You will need to work with a component state, which will be set after your API response.

Lets say this is your component:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: null
    }
    this.getData()
  }
  getData = () => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var uid = user.uid;
    axios.get('apilink here'+user.uid).then(function(response){
      var arr = Object.values(response.data);
      var listItems = arr.map(function(item){
        return <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      })
      this.setState({data: listItems})
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={{backgroundColor:'#F7F7F7'}}>
        <Content>
          {this.state.data}
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

This will let you load the state async response to your component